# How to use default XML serialization from within custom XML serialization methods

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have a class in .NET that implements IXmlSerializable.  I want to serialize its properties, but they may be complex types.  These complex types would be compatible with XML serialization, but they don't implement IXmlSerializable themselves.  From my ReadXml and WriteXml methods, how do I invoke the default read/write logic on the XmlReader/XmlWriter that is passed to me.

Perhaps code will make it clearer what I want:

```
public class MySpecialClass : IXmlSerializable
{
    public List<MyXmlSerializableType> MyList { get; set; }

    System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        //  Read MyList from reader, but how?
        //  Something like this?
        //  MyList = (List<MyXmlSerializableType>)
            reader.ReadObject(typeof(List<MyXmlSerializableType>));
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        //  Write MyList to writer, but how?
        //  Something like this?
        //  writer.WriteObject(MyList)

    }
}
```

Comment: Daniel, do you have more questions on this? I think you've been given the answer.

Comment: The ReadSubtree method was the key to solving the problem.  I haven't marked the current answer as accepted because it doesn't explain exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the writer, you could just create an XmlSerializer for the MySerializableType, then serialize the list through it to your writer.

```
void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
{
    // write xml decl and root elts here
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableType)); 
    s.Serialize(writer, MyList);
    // continue writing other elts to writer here
}
```

There is a similar approach for the reader.  **EDIT**: To read only the list, and to stop reading after the List is complete, but before the end of the stream, you need to use [ReadSubTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx) (credit Marc Gravell).

Comment: Re the last point: ReadSubtree: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx

Comment: Is the `XmlSerializer` instance lightweight enough to be instantiated on every call like this, or should it be cached?